# ajaxbutton how to prevent refresh of the page

Tags: ajax, yii

I succeed to use Ajax with Yii framework. 
I renderPartial a form  from within a list of post.

What I want to do is to prevent refresh when the user click on the ajaxbutton in the form.

In the beginning of the form I used the following code to activate ajax

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
    'id'=>'post-form',
    'enableAjaxValidation'=>true,
    'enableClientValidation'=>true,
)); ?>
```

and at the end of the page I simply have the ajaxbutton

```
<?php    echo CHtml::ajaxSubmitButton('Save'); ?>
```

in the action controller I  have the following

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='comment-form')
    {
    echo CActiveForm::validate($comment);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
```

When I click on the ajax button, it saves the data but refresh the page, so it display the form.
What I want is to stay on the page.

Is anyone to help ?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Make sure that your ajax response doesn't include again your JS files like jQuery. You might have created some kind of issue that is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11078103/prevent-loading-of-jquery-assets-with-ajaxbutton-ajaxsubmitbutton-on-yii-framewo

Answer (score 2):

you can prevent the page from refresh, or ask the user if he's sure he want to leave the page by this code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "Dude, are you sure you want to leave? Think of the kittens!";
    }
```

you can check this question: [Prevent any form of page refresh using jQuery/Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527041/prevent-any-form-of-page-refresh-using-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Does it means that if the user answer no ,  the comment won't be saved?  I would like to save it without redirecting.  @Prog-Mania

Comment: yes this shall shows a confirm box to the user asking if he's sure to reload the page and you can append a msg saying that there is some work is still processing in the background. @sanfisa

Answer (score 0):

I think you have some thing like `$this->redirect( ... ));`

in your controller after `$model->save()` , right?

so don't redirect there

Comment: In the action where I check the ajax call, I finished by returning the $comment variable @tinyByte